# Get exact type from dynamic object while keeping it typed

Tags: typescript

I've got class which have static property `params`. Via some under the hood magic(outside of typescript) each instance of this class will have access to `this.params` which will be more or less copy of static property. Static `params` is typed as `Record<string, ParamDef>` where `ParamDef` can have few different shapes.
That way I have help with adding new properties under static `params`.

`this.params` is typed as `typeof Class.params`
When I want to access `this.params.a.value` I get type as `string | number`. Is it possible to get here exact type (string) while keeping static property typed?

```js
type ParamDef = {
  type: "Text",
  value: string
} | {
  type: "Number",
  value: number
}

class Test {
  params!: typeof Test.params;

  constructor() {
    this.params.a.value; // string | number, expected string
  }
  static params: Record<string, ParamDef> = {
    a: {
      type: "Text",
      value: "someText"
    },
    b: {
      type: "Number",
      value: 3
    }
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJzgWwCIQGZQLxQN4BQUUokAXFAEQAqEAHsJQDRFQBucANgK4QUDOwBAEsAdgHMCAXygAffK1J8qAOW7IARhATNWHHstHqtCaQQIBjTnH78otQQuJhEKfgEIKSgPZYHwADoXJGR+AG5zYgtvUUEEbgtgbwQACgBKJ2ISAAthfiDXUIC4AP1eMKgAekqoOLFxOSgjTW0mKHpIRIgAE1qhetYsoeGh6qgAPQB+VilWQThgYQsoYLcKACUIaIRugB46iTb4EPQMAD4cTOI4CkIRpQoaekYWEbLlSn5vZAhaBkpBlApK8shpboDiA9VMZtLo3lxeBQAMyA2bEWZSIA)

Comment: You're looking for a `satisfies`-like operator, which can be emulated with a helper function, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wk00Lw).

Comment: Yes, that's exaclty what I needed, Thanks!